# How to delete files based on timestamp embedded in file name

Tags: c#, linq, delete-file

I am filtering files to delete based on creation timestamp. The piece of code that uses file creation works fine except that these files have embedded timestamp that somehow is different from create time. This causes a bunch of files to be missed for deletion.

This is what I am currently using:

```
public static void DeleteLogFiles(string sPath, DateTime dtDate, int iLogFileRetention)
{
    try
    {
        (from f in new DirectoryInfo(sPath).GetFiles()
            where f.CreationTime < dtDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(iLogFileRetention))
            select f
            ).ToList()
            .ForEach(f => f.Delete());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Timestamp embeddd in file name is formatted as MMddyyyyHHmmss.

```
ABCD_20240309000024.dat, but its last modified date is 03/12/2024
```

How do I modify the Linq statement above  to use embedded timestamp rather than create/modified date?

```
where f.FileName ?????
```

Comment: It's pretty silly to call `ToList` just so that you can call `ForEach`. Just use a `foreach` loop on the result of the LINQ query itself. The extra step provides no value.

Comment: Doing a `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { }` is such an anti-pattern. Do you just put that in all of your code?

Comment: @Enigmativity can you elaborate? What is the downside? I will remove try-catch block and ForEach, but any solutions to my question?

Comment: You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. When you capture everything and do nothing you are burying bugs and making your coding hard to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following helper method

```
static DateTime GetDateTime(string strTimestamp)
{
    // ABCD_20240309000024.dat
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strTimestamp);
    string[] parts = fileName.Split("_");
    string dateTimePart = parts[1];
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePart, "yyyyMMddFFFFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return dateTime;
}
```

and change the Linq as follows:

```
(from f in new DirectoryInfo(sPath).GetFiles()
    where (f.CreationTime < dtDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(iLogFileRetention))
    || GetDateTime(f.Name) < dtDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(iLogFileRetention)))
    select f
    ).ToList()
    .ForEach(f => f.Delete());
```

Please note that I used the date time format `yyyyMMdd` and you might need to change this.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It keeps returning no files to delete even though there are older file. In VS, I tried to to do a "Quick Watch" to see what the statement returns but get: "evaluation of method system.linq.systemcore_enumerabledebugview`1[[system.string, mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_items requires calling method system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.get_id, which cannot be called in this context."

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but I think it should do the job:

```cs
var filePaths = from filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)
                where DateTime.TryParseExact(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).Split('_').Last(),
                                             "MMddyyyyHHmmss",
                                             null,
                                             DateTimeStyles.None,
                                             out var creationTime) &&
                      creationTime < thresholdDate
                select filePath;
```

That `thresholdDate` is something that you should be calculating once, before the query, not within the query. Anything that you know will be the same for every input item should not be calculated within the query.